# Piezoelectric circuit behaviour

Tags: mosfet, piezoelectricity, mems, piezoelectric-effect

I am trying to study the piezoelectric material behaviour using S-Edit. Here, the force acting on the piezoelectric material is mapped to current. In the waveform viewer, I can see the current graph (in amps) has an increasing trend, where the Vin (in:V) has a decreasing trend over time. Would anyone please explain me how this circuit works? Thank you.

[image]

[image]